# Alternative download sites for Oracle tools

Tags: oracle, instantclient

I want to download the Oracle [Instant Client for Linux x86-64 (64-bit)](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html) for some time now.

Now I noticed that the website has been experiencing technical difficulties for the last couple of months.

To download anything from Oracle an account is required but the site basically crashes and burns on any attempt to login.

[image: site-oracle-experiencing-difficulties]

Are there alternatives ways / sites to get the Oracle tools?

**Update:** the Oracle site seems to only work on MS Windows! I'm on Linux Ubuntu 18.04 and FireFox. This makes the site crash and burn.

**Update 2:** I tried the Oracle YUM repository suggested by thatjeffsmith but that also is not an option when using RedHat or CentOS. The repo is intended to be used on Oracle Linux. It will create a massive dependency hell.

**Update 3**: it is possible to download on Linux if you have the url's using `wget` without account and login

```
wget --no-check-certificate -c --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/19800/oracle-instantclient19.8-basic-19.8.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

**update 4**: contrary to information published on Oracle.com I cannot use 19 client with 12.2 database. So I need the 12.2 versions for example oracle-instantclient12.2-basic-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm and these versions need to be downloaded manually with click-through

Comment: Personally I simply use `curl -O https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-basic-linuxx64.zip` or `curl -O https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/oracle-instantclient-basic-linuxx64.rpm`

Answer (score 7):

There's absolutely an alternative, and no need to have an oracle.com single-sign on account anymore.

If you go to the [oracle.com download page for the Instant Client](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html), you can download the archives without any need for sign-in.

Or you can go to our YUM repo.

[yum.oracle.com](https://yum.oracle.com)

You want to look for 'oracle-release-el7' or 'oracle-release-el6'

[image]

[You can read more about it here](https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/oracle-instant-client-rpms-now-available-on-oracle-linux-yum-server-yumoraclecom)

Comment: But, that *alternative* is still Oracle-owned, isn't it?

Comment: what does that have to do anything? the OP was asking for another place to get the instant client that didn't require an oracle login

Comment: Yes, it's our yum repo

Comment: @thatjeffsmith you don't need a login on OTN for the latest Instant Client versions, so non-Linux users can have an easy install experience too.

Comment: True, assuming the site isn't down...but everything on the yum repo is avail without a sign on..sorry, I'll amend my answer so that's clear!

Comment: The Oracle YUM repository is no option for other Linux distributions. This repository is intended to be used for Oracle Linux and on CentOS or RedHat this will create a dependency hell from which YUM will not recover.

Comment: @onknows does it matter if those distributions aren't supported? There is an alternative to Oracle.com for Linux, and this is it.

Comment: @onknows did you see Chris' comment? No need to sign in to download from o.com for the Instant Client

Answer (score 3):

If you have the download urls you can download without account and login, on Linux and also automate it using `wget` for example

```
wget --no-check-certificate -c --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/19800/oracle-instantclient19.8-basic-19.8.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

I am using the following URLs:

- https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/19800/oracle-instantclient19.8-basic-19.8.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm
- https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/19800/oracle-instantclient19.8-basiclite-19.8.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm
- https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/19800/oracle-instantclient19.8-sqlplus-19.8.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm
- https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/19800/oracle-instantclient19.8-tools-19.8.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm

Comment: You don't need the cookie etc options.  There is no click-through or login needed for those URLs.

Comment: I am trying to use WGET to retrieve version 11.2.0.4.0 but having no luck whatsoever. Using wget --no-check-certificate -c --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie"  https://download.oracle.com/otn/linux/instantclient/112040/instantclient-basiclite-linux.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip

Comment: @Calab We're finding the same issue. Look close at the URL - /otn_software/ links we can wget/curl with no issues. URLs with /otn/ download an html page. Interestingly, certain versions require a license agreement where others do not. Non-license agreement downloads are under /otn_software/, license /otn/. To tackle this, we're grabbing a later version of the instant client that is backwards compatible with our Oracle version. Hope this helps.